# Adding Column to Dataframe based on Function of other Column in R

Tags: r

A bit of an involved one I'm afraid - I’m having trouble adding a new column to a data frame based on applying a function to the value in another column.

I have a dataset LSOA_data, which looks like this:

```
> LSOA_data
                    LA      LSOA DomDem_kWh
     1:     Hartlepool E01011954    2968987
     2:     Hartlepool E01011969    2036143
    ---                                    
41726: Merthyr Tydfil W01001309    1943331
41727: Merthyr Tydfil W01001898    2417324
```

Each LSOA corresponds to a number of OAs, and I’ve defined a (working) function to find which OAs are in which LSOA:

```
LSOA_to_OAs <- function(x) {
    return(OA_LSOA_lookup$OA[which(OA_LSOA_lookup$LSOA==x)])
} # Get OAs within an LSOA
```

Based on the folowing table:

```
> OA_LSOA_lookup
                OA      LSOA
      1: W00003947 W01000737
      2: W00003948 W01000736
      3: W00003949 W01000737
      4: W00003950 W01000737
     ---                    
181405: E00176771 E01006583
181406: E00176772 E01006583
```

Each OA has a “Rurality” defined, and I am finding the mode "Rurality" within each OA in a given LSOA using another pair of (also working) functions:

```
Mode <- function(x) {
  ux <- unique(x)
  ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
} # Mode function - useful for attributing rurality to LSOAs (defined in a number of OA subgroups)

get_rurality_mode_LSOA <- function(x) {
  Mode(sapply(LSOA_to_OAs(x), function(y) {
     return(Rurality_OA_data[which(Rurality_OA_data$OA==(y))])
  }))
} # Get rurality for an LSOA
```

Based on the folowing table:

```
Rurality_OA_data
                OA Rurality
      1: E00000001       A1
      2: E00000003       A1
      3: E00000005       A1
     ---                   
181407: W00010264       D1
181408: W00010265       C1
```

I would like the mode rurality for all the OAs within each LSOA to appear in a new column in LSOA_data, something like:

```
> LSOA_data
                    LA      LSOA DomDem_kWh    Rurality
     1:     Hartlepool E01011954    2968987    C1    
     2:     Hartlepool E01011969    2036143    C1
    ---                                    
41726: Merthyr Tydfil W01001309    1943331    A1
41727: Merthyr Tydfil W01001898    2417324    B1
```

I’ve tried the following:

```
LSOA_data$Rurality <- with(LSOA_data, get_rurality_mode_LSOA(LSOA))
```

But I get a warning message:

```
Warning message:
In OA_LSOA_lookup$LSOA == x :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

And I get the same "Rurality" assigned to each entry in LSOA_data ("C1", which corresponds to the correct value for the first row in LSOA_data).

I’ve tested the “get_rurality_mode_LSOA()” function alone and it seems to work fine. "LSOA_data$LSOA_duplicate <- with(LSOA_data, LSOA)" gives an extra column with each LSOA listed, so it seems like the individual elements work. I’m a bit stumped as to what I’m doing wrong! Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why doesn't simply `merge` work?

Comment: In `get_rurality_mode_LSOA`, the call `LSOA_to_OAs(x)` is expecting a vectorized function, whereas your implementation of `LSOA_to_OAs` looks like a function where `x` should be a scalar

Comment: Re: RolandASc, thanks, that might be getting to the nub. Do you have a suggestion for how to change the function to achieve that? `LSOA_to_OAs(x)` seems to work when I put a scalar string in place of x (eg. `LSOA_to_OAs("E01011954")`), and I _think_ it should be receiving a scalar string from `get_rurality_mode_LSOA`, so a bit confused about why it's playing up still...

Comment: Re: akash87, thanks, `merge` won't work directly because one dataset is in terms of LSOAs and one in terms of OAs. I'm essentially trying to get Rurality in terms of LSOAs and merge with my main LSOA dataset (`LSOA_data`) in one step. Getting Rurality in terms of LSOAs first and then using `merge` would be another way, but I think I'd still have the same problem. I'm open to suggestions though!

Comment: you maybe want to say `sapply(x, LSOA_to_OAs)` in `get_rurality_mode_LSOA`?